# Receive a callback when third-party app successfully loaded the file in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to know if the third-party app successfully loaded the file?

My app has a user manual which is in pdf. When user taps the link to open it, my app calls for another app to open the file (implicit intent). The problem is, sometimes the 3rd-party app lags 2-5 secs before showing the pdf.

Now, what I want is to show a loading dialog in my app while the 3rd-party app is loading the pdf in the background and once the pdf is successfully loaded, receive a callback from the 3rd-party app to finish the loading dialog and show the user manual.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) within your app which serves the PDF file. You could then use a local broadcast or an event bus to have the content provider notify you when it's done serving the requested file. As your third-party viewer-app likely won't request the file until it's done initializing, you should get an event close to when your file is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you call an `Intent` to start an activity of another app, you couldn't interact with your app (activity, fragment) anymore, so I think it's not feasible.